# move a function to another schema

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, schema

It is possible to move a table from one schema to another:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table SET SCHEMA different_schema;
```

However, I cannot find the equivalent feature for moving a function from one schema to another.

How can I do this?

(version `8.3+`)

Comment: preferably without a drop / create

Comment: I ran into this helpful post recently, [but needed to move all the functions at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148055/change-schema-of-multiple-postgresql-functions-in-one-operation). Perhaps this can help someone in the same situation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Taken from the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterfunction.html):

```
ALTER FUNCTION name ( [ [ argmode ] [ argname ] argtype [, ...] ] )
SET SCHEMA new_schema
```

Comment: Note that if the function calls itself, the self-reference in the function body is not updated to the new schema.